# Injection and Surjection of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:\mathcal{P}(A)\mathbf{\times\mathcal{P}(}B)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$
  be defined as if $A_{1}\in\mathcal{P}(A)$
  and $B_{1}\in\mathcal{P}(B)$
  define $f(A_{1},B_{1})=A_{1}\cup B_{1}$

From part (a) of the question, I found that if A
  and B
  be two disjoint sets. That is $A\cap B=\emptyset
 .$ If $A_{1}\subseteq A$
  and $B_{1}\subseteq B$,
  then $A\cap(A_{1}\cup B_{1})=A_{1}$
  and $B\cap(A_{1}\cup B_{1})=B_{1}.$

I am supposed to use part (a) to show that the function is injective and surjective. I am not sure the next step to show why this is.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $f\colon X\to Y$ is a bijection (injective and surjective) if and only if there exists $g\colon Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g={\rm Id}_Y$ and $g\circ f={\rm Id}_X$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(A_1, B_1) = f(A_2, B_2)$. Then $A_1 \cup B_1 = A_2 \cup B_2$, so $A_1 = A \cap (A_1 \cup B_1) = A \cap (A_2 \cup B_2) = A_2$, and similarly, $B_1 = B_2$. So $(A_1, B_1) = (A_2, B_2)$, and therefore $f$ is injective.

To show $f$ is surjective, for any $X$ in $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$, note $f(A \cap X, B \cap X) = (A \cap X) \cup (B \cap X) = (A \cup B) \cap X = X$.