# Inverse of a function.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:\mathcal{P}(A)\mathbf{\times\mathcal{P}(}B)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$
  be defined as if $A_{1}\in\mathcal{P}(A)$
  and $B_{1}\in\mathcal{P}(B)$
  define $f(A_{1},B_{1})=A_{1}\cup B_{1}$

I am supposed to define the inverse. I know that

Let $f^{-1}:\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(A)\times\mathcal{P}(B)$

but I am not sure where to go from here.

EDIT** A and B are disjoint sets.

Comment: Are you assuming that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint?

Comment: Borderline duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383577/injection-and-surjection-of-sets

Comment: Ah sorry, A and B are disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

$$f:(A_1,B_1)\longrightarrow A_1\cup B_1$$

$$f^{-1}:S\longrightarrow (S\cap A,S\cap B)$$

Then
$$f^{-1}\circ f:(A_1,B_1)\longrightarrow \Big( (A_1\cup B_1)\cap A\ ;\ (A_1\cup B_1)\cap B\Big)$$
use De Morgan laws and note that $B_1\cap A=\varnothing=A_1\cap B$ to get $(A_1\cup B_1)\cap A=A_1$ and $(A_1\cup B_1)\cap B=B_1$

$$f\circ f^{-1}:S\longrightarrow (S\cap A)\cup ( S\cap B)$$
Use distributivity to get $S\cap (A\cup B)=S$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If $S\in\wp(A\cup B)$, consider the sets $S\cap A$ and $S\cap B$.

Comment: I don't think that's a hint anymore... :-)

Comment: @Asaf: If there’s one thing that I’ve learned from teaching, it’s that hints are almost never as big as you think they are!